# Mysql join:search with two tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have two tables

```
1)Users table (id,name);
1)Deals table (id,user_id(FK users),title,keyword);
```

When the user gives a keyword

I would like to get all deals from the deals table that matches `title` and `keyword` along with all deals of the users to match the keyword  `name`.

Is it possible to achieve this within single query I am confusing with it or do I need to run two query's

ie

1)Get all deals of that matches keyword and title from deals table.

2)Get all deals of the users matches the keyword in the `name` from user table  (probably a join query).

If I go with this approach how do I implement pagination on it??.

Answer (score 0):

This joins both tables and returns the rows that matches all 3 conditions.

```
SELECT d.id, d.title, d.keyword, u.name,
FROM Deals d
JOIN Users u ON u.id = d.user_id
WHERE (d.title = 'some title' AND d.keyword = 'some keyword')
OR u.name = 'some name'
```

If you don't want/need exact matches LIKE can be used instead, for instance

```
WHERE d.title LIKE '%some title%'
```

Comment: But it returns empty result if the keywords not match in deals table but entry found in the user table

Comment: So you want an OR condition than meaning _either_ 1) or 2) should match?

Comment: Yes i need OR condition